# Quantum fluctuations in the non-relativistic limit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-chromodynamics

Is there any way to describe quantum fluctuations in ordinary quantum mechanics? For instance, a proton fluctuating into a proton-$\pi^0$ state and then back to a proton?

What are the relevant equations in this case?

I need only be qualitative so a mixture of field/QM (i.e. field theory in the non-relativistic limit) theory would suffice too.

Comment: Conceptually, quantum fluctuations (if you mean virtual particles) are present in quantum field theory because uncertainty principle and mass energy equivalence both are present in the theory. Without special theory of relativity I don't think you can allow for virtual particles.